# Display column values in a row in DB2

Tags: db2

Is there a way to display some column value in a row followed by the remaining columns ? I have written the below query and it gives 3 rows as output however it should bring only 1 output.

```
select asset.assetnum, asset.serialnum, assetspec.alnvalue , assetspec.assetattrid  
from asset  
left outer join  assetspec on asset.assetnum = assetspec.assetnum  
and asset.classstructureid = assetspec.classstructureid  
where asset.assetnum='100' AND assetspec.ASSETATTRID IN ('XXX','YYY','ZZZ')
```

OUTPUT

```
ASSETNUM   SERIALNUM    ALNVALUE  ASSETATTRID
100            123         A         XXX
100            123         B         YYY
100            123         C         ZZZ
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
ASSETNUM   SERIALNUM    XXX    YYY   ZZZ
 100          123         A      B    C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with tab (ASSETNUM, SERIALNUM, ALNVALUE, ASSETATTRID) as (values
  (100, 123, 'A', 'XXX')
, (100, 123, 'B', 'YYY')
, (100, 123, 'C', 'ZZZ')
)
select ASSETNUM, SERIALNUM
, max(case ASSETATTRID when 'XXX' then ALNVALUE end) as XXX
, max(case ASSETATTRID when 'YYY' then ALNVALUE end) as YYY
, max(case ASSETATTRID when 'ZZZ' then ALNVALUE end) as ZZZ
from tab
group by ASSETNUM, SERIALNUM;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Your query brings the sample data output however I'm not sure how to fetch dynamic data using this query from the database since only the ASSETATTRID would be hardcoded and rest all would keep changing based on the asset.

Comment: You must construct the corresponding select statement dynamically in some some stored procedure based on all distinct values in the `ASSETATTRID` column. Some 2 steps process - insert the results into a temporary table fetching all distinct values to construct the final select statement on contents of this temp table like above.